# Change default font type

Tags: css, fonts

I want to change the default font used in my application. I have installed @font-face but not all of the elements were changed. Is it possible to use element 'body' and put font-family I want there? It'd be like :

```
body {
font-family: 'champagne'; }
```

I've put this :

```
@font-face {
font-family: Champagne;
src: url(css/font/Champagne_Limousines.TTF); }
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with php

Comment: `Is it possible..` Did you try? Give it a go, and if it doesn't work, come back and let us know.

Comment: `!important` is your friend

Comment: You may refer to this artice:


http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/ regarding the use of font-face.

Comment: @cillosis I've tried it before I ask, I mean, should I put something like @-feek recommend? Btw, thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using font-family on body like this

```
body {
font-family: 'Font Name'; 
}
```

It should apply to all elements if its not applying means font-family properties already defined for other elements as well. for example

```
p{
font-family: Arial; 
}
```

for that you can use * selector like this

```
*{
    font-family: 'Font Name' !important;  
    }
```

which will override all other elements, also you have to use web fonts for it and all other formats as well to support all browsers 
EOT,WOFF,SVG & TTF

your Font face should look like this

```
@font-face
{
font-family: 'FontName';
src: url('FontName.eot');
src: url('FontName.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('FontName.woff') format('woff'),
url('FontName.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('FontName.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```